# Use New Text Value Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set a new text value from a form based on a previous textbox, but .val seems to only call from the originally set value, not the changed value. What functions should I be using?

example below - retrieves original value='please' text, but not any changes made to form 1. Variable helpMe set to the current field val... not sure how to make it detect the update and return a new value for field2.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var helpMe = $("#field").val();
    
        $("#field").change(function(){
            $("#field2").val(function(n,c){
             return c + helpMe;
            });
            
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Attach a function to run when an element has been changed:</p>
    
    Form 1 <input class="field" type="text" id="field" value="please"></p>
    Form 2<input class="field" type="text" id="field2">
```

Comment: `helpMe` doesn't magically update its value, you need to pull the retrieval: `var helpMe = $("#field").val();` into the change handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your trying to populate form1 value and append it to form2, then you would need to capture the new value inside the change function, not at document.ready which would set the value only during load.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#field").change(function(){
            var helpMe = $("#field").val();
            $("#field2").val(function(n,c){
             return c + helpMe;
            });
            
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Attach a function to run when an element has been changed:</p>
    
    Form 1 <input class="field" type="text" id="field" value="please"></p>
    Form 2<input class="field" type="text" id="field2">
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense! Appreciate the help.